# How to set up development environment for a particular version of ios

Tags: ios

I work for a company that offers software solutions to the care industry. I have written an Android app that the care worker use to provide home care.

I've been asked to replicate the same app on the iOS platform. They have ordered a mini Mac  2.6Ghz Core i7 16GB ram machine to come next week. I know the Hardware is suitable for writing for the latest iPhone but what if carers have an iPhone 4, which alot will.

How do i set up my development environment to ensure the app works on earlier phones?

I've looked at the latest Stanford Uni tutorials(2013/2014) and they differ from the 2010 tutorials, this makes me think the later code will not run on iPhone 4 say.

Thanks in advance

Matt

Comment: Why do you think it won't run on the iPhone 4?

Comment: i'm not sure if it would or not. sorry if it's an odd question:)

Comment: No welcome to the iOS community, whoever down voted :) Please bare with me while i find my feet.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS applications can run on previous devices. In Xcode you can see that in the storyboards it allows you to use a single storyboard for all versions of the iPhone. The only difference is the screen size: so you have work with screen constraints to adjust to different sizes.

It should not be an issue if people have an iPhone 4.

Comment: ok great! One less problem. I best start looking for some docs and tutorials. thanks

Comment: Please choose my answer!

Comment: i'm going to, but it will not let me accept for another 2 mins yet;)